# Суть построения приложений с помощью swift

Tags: xcode, swift, objective-c, iphone

Немного не понятно, сама суть построения приложений с помощью swift ?
какая будет взаимосвязь с cocoa?
пока только вижу в доке уровень си языка (переменные, массивы), где классы, как подключать frameworkи? подскажите, может не туда смотрю )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашел:

[Using swift with Cocoa and Objective-c](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/BuildingCocoaApps.pdf)

Comment: Судя по топику я подумал вы ее уже прочитали ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Всеж ясно. Создайте проект не пустой а с какой либо датой и все там понятно.